# Huge data transfer usage on RDS w/ MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We started using RDS last month for our database needs but we're seeing "data transfer in" usage of about 3~6gb EACH DAY. Our database size is about 4gb. How's that possible? Is this some misconfiguration on my part?
We're also seeing 8~14gb of "data transfer out" each day and I really can't say why.

It's my first time using AWS (we're also using S3 but I've checked the reports and everything is accurate there) so I'm kinda lost.

For context, our application is built in JSF2 and we use Hibernate. We also have a web service running on PHP for a mobile application. We expect anywhere between 20~200 users daily 24/7.

I've set up the security groups to only allow inbound from our servers (and I removed all rules for outbound, is that fine?).

Our instance: `Single-AZ` class `db.t2.micro`

Comment: At the risk of insulting your intelligence, which is not my intention... are you aware that "data transfer" means "bytes on the network" and not just "data" (the stuff databases store and retrieve)? 
 For example, each `SELECT` query you run transfers data in -- the string containing the SQL, the query itself -- and also transfers data out -- the results.  Data transfer is unrelated to the size of the stored data -- it's all about traffic.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm aware of that. I just find it weird that we're seeing up to 6gb of data being sent to the server each day while our database isn't growing up not even 10mb/day. Maybe it's Hibernate's fault? TBH I don't really know how it works behind the curtains. We *do* have some pages that makes a lot of queries every few minutes but these numbers seems absurd...

Comment: You are not charged for data transfer within the same region, but if your app is in another region, queries will count against your data transfer. Likewise if you have an RDS replica in another region, it'll cost.

Comment: Note that you could have a lot of data transfer even if you run a lot of SELECT queries. The SELECT query itself has some length to it. Suppose you had very long SELECT queries, like 10KB in length. If you run just 8 such queries per second on average, that would be 6GB just in SQL queries, not even counting data.

Comment: If it's data, if you do a lot of UPDATEs, that would replace data. You could ship a lot of data into the database in UPDATEs without making any net increase in size.

Comment: Chances are you can reduce that data usage by caching at the application level.

Comment: @BillKarwin we don't do a lot of updates but yes, we do make a lot of SELECTs every few minutes, so I guess that would make sense... before migrating to RDS we didn't really have to check on bandwidth usage so it kinda took us by surprise.